# Set field value to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a html field called styles, which gets its value from a php value:

```
<input name="styles" value="'.$colorstyle.'" id="styles" >
```

Now I have a javascript code, in which I need the value of the field to place in:

```
this.colours = {
        'normal' : {
            'txt' : "rgb(255,255,255)",
            'arrow':"rgb(0,0,0)",

        }
    };
```

I have tried below code in the javascript file, but I'm not getting the right output. Also, I don't know how to debug this.

```
var arrowcolor = document.getElementById('styles').innerHTML
    this.colours = {
        'normal' : {
            'txt' : "rgb(255,255,255)",
            'arrow':"'+arrowcolor+'",
        }
    };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Comment: `var arrowcolor = document.getElementById('styles').value` would be more appropriate or `'arrow':document.getElementById('styles').value`

Comment: You can use document.getElementById('styles').value; if you want to debug JS, simply put debugger; keyword in your javascript code and keep developer tools open. This would create a break point and you will be able to debug any js file easily.

Comment: oh, btw  you need to set the ID on the element

Answer (score 0):

Use value instead of innerHTML

```
var arrowcolor = document.getElementById('styles').value
    this.colours = {
        'normal' : {
            'txt' : "rgb(255,255,255)",
            'arrow':arrowcolor,
        }
    };
```